# JQuery function call from HTML page

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi I have a function in an external js file called 'nsslider'. Its just a simple slider.

The external js script is setup like below

```
(function($){
     $.nsslider = function(element,settings){
          //All my script is here
     };
})(jQuery);
```

I am trying this on my HTML page and it doesn't work

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='slider.jquery.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript'>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.nsslider(
        '#slider',
        {
            'auto' : true,
            'auto_delay' : 4000,
            'slide_speed' : 500,
            'looparound' : true,
            'controls_hide_delay' : 1000
        }           
    );
);
</script>
```

Any ideas on this, I'm not great with javascript and it's quriks. Much appreciated.

Comment: More information? What doesn't work? Have you used a debugger to see what's the error?

Comment: I don't see the jquery library script linked in your page.

Comment: Can you show us the order in which you're linking to the javascript files ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's a jQuery jQuery plugin. Also make sure you added jQuery to your source.

I think it should be called like:

```
$(function(){
    $('#slider').nsslider(
        {
            'auto' : true,
            'auto_delay' : 4000,
            'slide_speed' : 500,
            'looparound' : true,
            'controls_hide_delay' : 1000
        }           
    );
});
```

Do you got a link to the plugin?

Comment: No the slider is passed the '#slider' element and works everything out from there. It's strange because if I wrap my external script in a $(document).ready and put the function call within that and then remove the call from the HTML page, it works. But obviously I need to be able to call the function from different page.

Comment: I see your mistake, you are not closing your $(document).ready(function(){, you are missing 1 } before your );

Comment: It works now. Always the way, 2 hours for one brace. Thanks very much Niels